# Confusion about required documents for a chilean work visa

Tags: paperwork, chile, working-visas

I am looking at the requisites for a temporary work visa for Chile. The [official instructions](http://www.extranjeria.gob.cl/media/2016/09/TE16-ISO-TEMPORARIA-POR-MOTIVOS-LABORALES.pdf) (PDF, in Spanish) mention that in order to get one, you need a photocopy of your last tourist card:

> 1 fotocopia de la ÚLTIMA Tarjeta de Turismo. Si se la extravió, puede solicitar un duplicado en las oficinas de Policía Internacional (Eleuterio Ramírez Nº 852, Santiago).

Translation:

> 1 photocopy of the LAST tourist card. If it has been lost, you can request a duplicate in the offices of the International Police (Eleuterio Ramírez no. 852, Santiago).

I have been to Chile before. You get the tourist card when you enter the country and **you have to surrender it to the police** when you leave.

So in my case, I never lost the tourist card. I just gave it to the police at the airport as requested. I never thought of making a photocopy, because I did not know I would need it for a Visa later.

Am I missing something here? Do I need to go to Chile as a tourist again, just to photocopy a new tourist card, and then have to come back to my country to request a temporary resident visa?

Comment: What I've heard is that work visa in Chile is only for people that actually live in the country. So, if you live in the country it means that you should have the tourist card.

Comment: @Renan while I don't know the requisits of the visa you mentioned, the PDF you showed says "Exclusive for people living in Santiago" in the title, so if you are already living in Santiago and don't have a work visa, means you got here as a tourist and should have the tourist card with you.